# Is it possible to run perl script in Visual Basics?

Tags: perl

i have written Perl script but i want to run that Perl script in visual basics so that it will be easy to create front end,
my question is weather it is possible or not to connect Perl script with VB?

Comment: There is no simple way to connect Perl to Visual Basic in Visual Studio. Microsoft has no support for this. However, you could write a program that, using the console, would execute a perl program. However, I would not recommend this, instead, I would recommend trying to learn a new language like C# or Java.

Comment: can i do same thing using QT developer??

Comment: You can execute another program in almost any language. You should be able to do this in QT developer, but QT developer wont be able to help you with the syntax or execution of the perl program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to create a VB form that will allow you to enter the parameters for your script, and then run the script for you with the given parameters.

To do this, just use the [Shell function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk.aspx) from VB to execute Perl with whatever command line you create.